# How to changing barTintColor without animation on iOS7?

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar, bartintcolor

On iOS7, we can changing navigation bar's  color by

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

But this method has a fade animation when changing the barTintColor, So does anynone know how to prevent this animation and change the color immediately?

To be more specific, I wrote a test program whose window's root controller is navigationController. And in the navigationController, there is a view controller with 3 buttons. 3 buttons all bind to the following action:

```
- (void)onClick:(id)sender
{
    UIColor *color = nil;
    if (sender == self.redButton)
    {
        color = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    else if (sender == self.blueButton)
    {
        color = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
    else if (sender == self.blackButton)
    {
        color = [UIColor blackColor];
    }

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = color

//    [UIView animateWithDuration:0 animations:^{
//        self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = color;
//    }];

//    [CATransaction begin];
//    [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
//    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = color;
//    [CATransaction commit];

}
```

Both changing the animation duration to 0 or using `[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES]` doesn't work, the animation still exists.

Hope someone can help, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Try setting barTintColor to nil before setting it again.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = nil;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = color;
```

I had a similar problem, and it fixed it for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. 
I have my navigation bar that fades from one color to another based on gestures and this works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable the implicit animation. You can do this as follows:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setDisableActions: YES];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:125.0/255.0 green:90.0/255.0 blue:146.0/255.0 alpha:1];

[CATransaction commit];
```

This technique works for any implicit animation. An implicit animation is an animation that's created for you by iOS when you change an animatable property. See here for more information:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coreanimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html

Comment: Sorry, Did you try it on navigationBar.barTintColor? It just doesn't work.

Comment: Didn't work for me on a UITabBarController.tabBar.barTintColor.

Answer (score 1):

Set `translucent` property on the `UINavigationBar` to `NO`, then reset it after the bar tint is changed

```
self.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
self.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor magentaColor];
self.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

Comment: This is the only approach in this thread that worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try with

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0 animations:^{
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
}];
```

Comment: Did you run this code ? The animation still exsits and the animation duration doesn't change.